# Libreoffice CALC formula find value

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

I have some ean codes that I need to get from sheet2 to sheet1.
The list are randomly so i need a search formula of som kind. It`s way over my head. Is it possible? 
This one gives me error: #N/A

```
#N/A=INDEX($Sheet2.$B$2:$B$100;MATCH(A2;$Sheet2.$A$2:$A$100;0))
```

[image: So i guess i should be about]

Comment: Use VLOOKUP or MATCH plus INDEX.  Random isn't a problem.

Comment: I tried this: =INDEX($Sheet2.$B$2:$B$100;MATCH(A2;$Sheet2.$A$2:$A$100;0)) Gives me error #N/A

Comment: If you're testing this on the literal example in the question, the product names don't match because of an extra space between "Item" and the number in sheet1.

Comment: Omg, I see that know. I have struggled with this :P